# How to trigger shell script on Unix via email from Exchange Server

Tags: shell-script, email

I have been asked to setup an automated trigger on Unix upon receiving a certain kind of email from MS Exchange server.

The requirement is to trigger a shell script when any person from a fixed list of senders sends an email via MS Exchange server to a designated email account on unix.

For example:

Email from rob81@host1.com (Exchange Server) sends an email to unix@host2.com (Linux) with the subject: Unlock Account X

This ideally should trigger a shell script that will have code to unlock Account X.

Is there a way to configure this on Unix so that upon receiving an email as described above, I can trigger a shell script?

Comment: `procmail` might help you in this case

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are multiple solutions to this problem. As suggested by *Rahul* in the comments, I would use procmail and edit .procmailrc  to something like this:

```
:0
* ^From.*someone.i.dont.like@somewhere.org
* !^FROM_DAEMON
* !^FROM_MAILER
* ^Subject:.*Unlock
| /path/to/your/script
```